# No-ip hostname change back to IP at the moment I acces the site

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, noip

Im using the no-ip free service, i have register a hostname (example.ddns.net, for example) and this hostname is pointing at my IP and my port (8080), the problem is that when I access to this hostname from my browser it change back to my ip in the moment I enter the site
This is a problem because im trying to use TLS on this ip and port, but I got SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN or ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME-INVALID
Because the certificate is only valid for example.ddns.net not for x.x.x.x:8080
please help!

Comment: **Your webserver is sending redirect(s) with the address instead of the name. Fix your webserver.** In particular if you enter only the domainname (without the scheme prefix https://) in a browser, it initially sends an HTTP request which your server may be trying to redirect to HTTPS -- but doing so badly. FYI DNS points to an address not a port, and SSL/TLS certificates are for the hostname (usually) or address (rarely) or a combination but NOT for a port.

Comment: Thank you so much!
This was really helpfull I got it working now!

Comment: How did you fix it? @MarcosRojas